# When defining a new math alphabet how to scale its letters?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, declare

I am defining a new alphabet with `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}`. I used to use the fonts by `\usepackage[scaled=1.15]{urwchancal}` but this changes all `\mathcal` letters, when using the declare math I can select where to use this alphabet but I don't know how to scale the `\mathpzc` as it was scaled in `\usepackage[scaled=1.15]{urwchancal}`.

Is there a way to make `\DeclareMathAlphabet[scaled=1.15]{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}` or something like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in `ot1pzc.fd` and extract the relevant information, so you can define a different font family with scaling.

```
\ProvidesFile{ot1pzc.fd}
   [2020/03/25 font definitions for OT1/pzc.]

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{pzc}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}{
   <-> pzcmi7t
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{sl}{<->ssub * pzc/m/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{pzc}{m}{n}{<->ssub * pzc/m/it}{}

\endinput
```

We need `\DeclareFontFamily` and the first `\DeclareFontShape` instructions.

```
\documentclass{article}

% from ot1pzc.fd
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{modpzc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{modpzc}{m}{it}{<-> s*[1.15] pzcmi7t}{}
% define the math alphabet
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{modpzc}{m}{it}

% just for comparison (remove it)
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathunscaledpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

$A\mathpzc{A}B\mathpzc{B}$

$A\mathunscaledpzc{A}B\mathunscaledpzc{B}$

\end{document}
```

I added `\mathunscaledpzc` just to compare the results.

[image]

But you can more simply load `urwchancal`. With the `mathscr` option the standard `\mathcal` is still available and (the clone of) Zapf Chancery is obtained with `\mathscr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scaled=1.15,mathscr]{urwchancal}

\begin{document}

$A\mathscr{A}B\mathscr{B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]